# Import and Append Android Database from SD Card

Tags: android, database

I have 2 apps, a free version and a paid version. Each version allows the user to backup their database data to the SD card. The databases being saved are exactly the same (i.e. they have the same columns defined).

If the user wants to import the data from the free version to the paid version, I can do this easily if the user hasn't saved any data in the paid version, because I can just grab the free version's database files from the SD Card and use those files for the paid version by copying them into the app.

I need information about importing the database information from the free version into the paid version, after the user has already saved information in the paid version. In this case, I can't simply overwrite the files. I think I need to manually grab each row from the tables of the free version on the SD card, and add each row one at a time into the databases of the paid version.

My questions are:

1. what options are available to me to accomplish this? Is there a good or easy way to pull in the information from the database files on the SD Card, and then append each row into the database of my app?`
2. If there are multiple options available to me, of the options available, would one option be considered the best option to pursue?